Computer doesn't wake up after sleep
My computer doesn't wake up after sleep. I have an RGB keyboard and mouse, and if I interact with either one of them while asleep they both turn on and start glowing like my computer is about to wake up, but it just never turns on.
I've also found these error messages in the log:
Aug 08 16:54:06 ManjaroGamingPC org_kde_powerdevil[1159]: busno=4, sleep-multiplier= 2.00, Testing for unsupported feature 0xdd returned Error_Info[DDCRC_RETRIES in ddc_write_read_with_retry, causes: DDCRC_DDC_DATA(4), DDCRC_NULL_RESPONSE, DDCRC_DDC_DATA(5)]
Aug 08 16:54:06 ManjaroGamingPC org_kde_powerdevil[1159]: Turning off dynamic sleep and retrying
Aug 08 16:54:07 ManjaroGamingPC org_kde_powerdevil[1159]: busno=4, sleep-multiplier = 1.00, Retesting for unsupported feature 0xdd returned Error_Info[DDCRC_RETRIES in ddc_write_read_with_retry, causes: DDCRC_DDC_DATA(2), DDCRC_NULL_RESPONSE, DDCRC_DDC_DATA(2), DDCRC_NULL_RESPONSE, DDCRC_DDC_DATA(3), DDCRC_NULL_RESPONSE]
Aug 08 16:54:10 ManjaroGamingPC org_kde_powerdevil[1159]: busno=4, sleep-multiplier= 2.00, Testing for unsupported feature 0x00 returned Error_Info[DDCRC_RETRIES in ddc_write_read_with_retry, causes: DDCRC_DDC_DATA(10)]
Aug 08 16:54:10 ManjaroGamingPC org_kde_powerdevil[1159]: Turning off dynamic sleep and retrying
Aug 08 16:54:10 ManjaroGamingPC kernel: usb 1-2: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82
Aug 08 16:54:11 ManjaroGamingPC org_kde_powerdevil[1159]: busno=4, sleep-multiplier = 1.00, Retesting for unsupported feature 0x00 returned Error_Info[DDCRC_RETRIES in ddc_write_read_with_retry, causes: DDCRC_DDC_DATA(6), DDCRC_NULL_RESPONSE, DDCRC_DDC_DATA(2), DDCRC_NULL_RESPONSE]
Aug 08 16:54:11 ManjaroGamingPC org_kde_powerdevil[1159]: busno=4, DDCRC_RETRIES failure reading all unsupported features. Setting DREF_DDC_USES_DDC_FLAG_FOR_UNSUPPORTED
Aug 08 16:54:16 ManjaroGamingPC kernel: usb 1-2: 1:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x82

System info:
Operating System: Manjaro Linux 
KDE Plasma Version: 6.0.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.4.0
Qt Version: 6.7.2
Kernel Version: 6.10.0-3-MANJARO (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 24 × AMD Ryzen 9 5900X 12-Core Processor
Memory: 31.3 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

Edit: Someone also changed the tag from 'sleep' to 'hibernate', but I am not talking about plasma's 'hibernate' option, I'm talking about it's 'sleep' option. Through I think the technical term for what it's doing is suspending, the error message also talks about sleep and not hibernating, so I'm changing the tag to 'suspend'.

There is "sleep", where a process voluntarily surrenders the CPU for a time. There is "suspend" where the system saves itself to RAM and enters a low power state.  There is "hibernate", where the system saves itself to disk, and turns the computer off. "Suspend" requires a modern CPU, with controllable power states. "Hibernation" requires a RAM-sized, contiguous swap space.

The claim with the need for "contiguous" swap hasn't been true for decades, and suspend needs a CPU from past ca 1996 (i.e., one with ACPI support) on x86. That's not "modern" by any sensible meaning of the word in the context of computers. When suspending fails, it's almost universally due to broken non-CPU hardware or drivers.

This answer also doesn't seem to address the problem the asker is having, although they forgot to ask a question.
